# RoR 3 on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, windows-7

I am a complete beginner in RoR.

Is it possible (or advised) to run RoR 3.x on a windows machine (xampp) for development? I was able to run the start page (http://localhost:3000), but not any subpages (http://localhost:3000/posts), because the rewrite does not seem work. I read about Phusion Passenger, but that is not available for WIN

thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible to run RoR3 on windows. I'm running it. What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Try this one: http://railstutorial.org/

Comment: Soz for the delayed response: I am getting a 404. When I add the path to the public folder (`./public/controllername/index.html`) I get that file, so for some reason rails is not dispatching the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi im real beginner in rails, too

i also tried to get rails running on windows and it was just frustrating. i installed ubuntu and everything was much easier

Comment: What error are you getting in installation? If you don't post your error how come other solve it??? So you should provide complete information with error you are getting. it somehow helps others to know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

The following guide may be useful - http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-windows